# How use class in annotation Kotlin

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I want to create an annotation that receives a Class parameter, the example in JAVA should be

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

    Class<Comparable<?>> comparator();
}
```

I suppose that in Kotlin should be:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CustomAnnotation(

    val comparator: Class<Comparable<*>>
)
```

But in Kotlin get an error message `Invalid type of annotation member` so how should be the equivalent in Kotlin to accept a class as parameter?

Comment: How about `Comparable<Any>`?

Comment: The documentation on annotations shows how: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the language reference on [annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#constructors):

> If you need to specify a class as an argument of an annotation, use a Kotlin class (`KClass`).

So, instead of Java `Class<Comparable<*>>`, use the Kotlin equivalent: `KClass<Comparable<*>>`:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class CustomAnnotation(
    val comparator: KClass<Comparable<*>>
)
```